# Sentinel based find with conditional fallback to std::find

Tags: c++, performance, search, c++14

I've got bored, so I decided to write a code using ancient knowledge of sentinels.

**Sentinel based find**

Basically what we do is put value that is needed to find at the end, and then write an endless loop. Breaking from loop happens in the body of it, so one branch (which probably won't make much, since it is a loop branch, but still) is eliminated. Requires the type to have `noexcept` copy assign and `noexcept` copy construct (in C++17, since I guess `T t = value` will have guaranteed copy elision).

Is there any possibilities to make this faster without compromising functionality?

```
#ifndef FAST_FIND_HPP
#define FAST_FIND_HPP

#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

namespace impl
{
    template <typename BidirIt, typename T>
    BidirIt find(std::true_type, BidirIt first, BidirIt last, const T& value)
    {
        if (first == last)
        {
            return last;
        }

        auto real_last = std::prev(last);
        if (*real_last == value)
        {
            return real_last;
        }


        auto copy = *real_last;
        *real_last = value;

        auto it = first;
        for (; ; ++it)
        {
            if (*it == value)
                break;
        }

        *real_last = copy;

        if (it == real_last)
        {
            return last;
        }

        return it;

    }

    template <typename BidirIt, typename T>
    BidirIt find(std::false_type, BidirIt first, BidirIt last, const T& value)
    {
        return std::find(first, last, value);
    }
}


template <typename BidirIt, typename T>
BidirIt find(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, const T& value)
{
    return impl::find(std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)> >::value> {}, 
        first, last, value);
    //I'd like to allow T to be different from *first

}

#endif
```

Usage:

```
#include "fast_find.hpp"
#include "randomsequence.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10'000'000);
    random_int_generator<> gen(0, 10'000); //generate values in range
    gen(v.begin(), v.end());

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), n);
    if (it != v.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Found it!\n" << *it << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Sadness\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the `random_int_generator<>`, **do not review this**, I posted it to make it easier for you to benchmark if needed:

```
#pragma once

#include <random>

template <typename T = int, class Engine = std::random_device>
class random_int_generator
{
    Engine engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist;
public:
    random_int_generator(T begin = 0, T end = std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) :
        dist(begin, end)
    {

    }

    template <typename OutputIt>
    void operator()(OutputIt first, OutputIt last)
    {
        while (first != last)
        {
            *first++ = dist(engine);
        }
    }

    T operator()()
    {
        return dist(engine);
    }
};
```

You can find current version in my [github repo](https://github.com/simmplecoder/custom-library) (it's a mess, I hope you won't mind that).

Comment: I would like to note that `makefile` in the github repo is written by someone who've never written `makefile`'s before, so be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)> >::value>
```

is a very complicated synonym for

```
std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>>
```

in this context, because all the *UnaryTypeTrait*s are defined by the standard to be "publicly and unambiguously derived" (directly or indirectly) from their *BaseCharacteristic* of `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`.

---

Your code returns `std::prev(last)` when `*last == value`, even if there's an instance of `value` prior to that in the sequence. This isn't a bug (presumably), but it's surprising enough that you should probably document it explicitly somewhere; otherwise I'd assume a function named `find` to have semantics *exactly* the same as `std::find` [alg.find] — i.e., "return an iterator to the first matching element".

---

Checking `is_nothrow_copy_assignable<...>` doesn't really buy you anything, if you aren't going to check `is_nothrow_copy_constructible<...>` and `is_nothrow_equality_comparable<...>` and `is_nothrow_prefix_incrementable<...>`... and so on, for all the other operations you do inside the "critical section" of your function (between the line where you blow away the old value of `*real_last` and the line where you restore it).

Alternatively, you could use a `try`/`catch` to make sure that you always restore the old value of `*real_last`. Since C++ lacks the "`finally`" construct that exists in languages such as Java and Python, I recommend a generic scope-guard construct such as [`Auto()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38289141/1424877) if you find yourself doing this kind of thing very often.

---

<s>Your code has a problem with *empty ranges*.</s>

Comment: Thanks for review. I'm checking if the range is empty at the beginning.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Strike that point, then. :)

Comment: I've implemented something similar to your `Auto(), but renamed it to [scope_exit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145801/scope-exit-macro).