# SCOPE_EXIT implementation

Tags: c++, error-handling, c++14, boost, scope

I'm a fanboy of the Boost library and I've used Boost's components extensively in my C++03 project. The team decided to merge several pieces of code including my project. I will get the C++14 environment, but I have to drop the Boost library, so I'd like to replace `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT` with a modern C++ technique.

Here is `SCOPE_EXIT`'s implementation, with a short example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

template <typename Lambda>
class ScopeGuard
{
public:
    ScopeGuard(const Lambda& func)
        : committed_(false), valid_(true), rollbackFunc_(func) {}

    ~ScopeGuard() noexcept
    {
        if (valid_ && !committed_)
            rollbackFunc_();
    }

    ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
    ScopeGuard& operator=(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;

    ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&& other)
        : committed_(other.committed_), valid_(other.valid_), rollbackFunc_(other.rollbackFunc_)
    {
        other.valid_ = false;
    }

    ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&& other)
    {
        committed_ = other.committed_;
        valid_ = other.valid_;
        rollbackFunc_ = other.rollbackFunc_;
        other.valid_ = false;
        return *this;
    }

    void commit() const { committed_ = true; }

private:
    mutable bool committed_;
    bool valid_;
    Lambda rollbackFunc_; 
};

template <typename Lambda>
ScopeGuard<Lambda> makeScopeGuard(Lambda&& func)
{
    return ScopeGuard<Lambda>(func);
}


#define MY_CONCATENATE_NX(A, B) A ## B
#define MY_CONCATENATE(A, B) MY_CONCATENATE_NX(A, B)

#define SCOPE_EXIT(f) auto MY_CONCATENATE(EXIT, __LINE__) = makeScopeGuard(f);


int foo(const char*) noexcept;
bool bar(int) noexcept;
void baz(int) noexcept;

int main() {
    int f = foo("/dev/random");
    if (!f)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    SCOPE_EXIT([f](){ baz(f); })
    int b = 1;
    bar(b);
    // baz(f)

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Godbolt gcc 7.2 -std=c++14 -O2](https://godbolt.org/g/XxoC5G)

[VS2017 -W4 /EHsc /O2](https://godbolt.org/g/MFZVvo)

gcc's assembly is pretty short, however MSVC's assembly is so long (about 70 lines) and I can't understand what's going on. (I am not familiar with the Windows environment.)

Did I miss something, or is it a bad optimization of MSVC?

Comment: gcc didn't compile any of the ScopeGuard code.

Comment: @MillieSmith Then that is absolute good optimization. Don't you think?

Comment: @ByoungchanLee, I believe better version was already shown during Andrei Alexandrescu's talk, I belive in cppcon 2014. I implemented it, made nano modifications, and then posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145801/scope-exit-macro).

Comment: @MillieSmith It has to put the destructor somewhere (it has a side affect). The rest of the code can be elided but it still needs to call `baz()` It can see that `bar()` is `noexcpt` and `commit()` is not called. So the rest of the code can be removed.

Comment: `rollbackFunc_ = other.rollbackFunc_;` in `ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&& other)` is illegal. Error C3853 '=': re-initializing a reference or assignment through a reference-to-function is illegal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Move semantics:

The `makeScopeGuard()` function accepts the lambda by r-value ref; but passes a normal ref to the constructor of `ScopeGuard`.

```
template <typename Lambda>
ScopeGuard<Lambda> makeScopeGuard(Lambda&& func)
{
    return ScopeGuard<Lambda>(func);
}
```

You should either update `ScopeGuard` to take the function by r-value ref or change the `makeScopeGuard()` take a normal ref (to be consistent).

Personally I would pass the r-value ref through to the `ScopeGuard`.

```
template <typename Lambda>
ScopeGuard<Lambda> makeScopeGuard(Lambda&& func)
{
    return ScopeGuard<Lambda>(std::move(func)); // Need the move here
                                                // a named value is not an r-value ref.
}
```

Also need to update `ScopeGuard`

```
ScopeGuard(Lambda&& func)
    : committed_(false)               // Please one line per variable
                                      // Just like in normal code
                                      // were you declare one variable per line.
    , valid_(true)
    , rollbackFunc_(std::move(func))  // Need the move again.
{}
```

#### No Except

Normally the move operators are marked `noexcept`. Unless you have a good reason not to I would continue that norm.

```
ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
```

#### Move by swapping.

The easiest way to move something is to swap it.

```
// Now we could implement this with a swap.
// But this seems trivial enough So this is fine.
ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
    : committed_(other.committed_)        // One variable per line please.
    , valid_(other.valid_)
    , rollbackFunc_(other.rollbackFunc_)
{
    // Disabled the moved from.
    other.valid_ = false;
}

ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
{
    // Here we are doing a copy (why not invoke the copy constructor)?
    // Followed by marking it `false`.
    committed_ = other.committed_;
    valid_ = other.valid_;
    rollbackFunc_ = other.rollbackFunc_;
    other.valid_ = false;
    return *this;
}
```

I would write like this:
I personally think it is easier to read like this.

```
ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
    : committed_(false)
    , valid_(false)
    , rollbackFunc_([](){})
{
    swap(other);
}

ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
{
    swap(other);
    other.valid_ = false;
    return *this;
}

void swap(ScopeGuard& other) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(committed_,    other.committed_);
    swap(valid_,        other.valid_);
    swap(rollbackFunc_, other.rollbackFunc_);
}
```

#### Abuse of mutable

```
mutable bool committed_;
```

Not sure I like this. Is this because you have a const value and want to get around the constness of the object?

Mutable objects are meant to represent objects that are not part of the full state of the object. i.e. a cached or computed part of the state that can be re-calculated.

`committed_` is very much part of the objects main state. So I would not mark it mutable.

That of course means you have to remove the `const` off the `commit` method.

```
void commit()       { committed_ = true; }
              ^^^^^ removed const
```

It is changing the state so its not really a const method.

#### Commit

There seems to be no way to call commit!!!

```
SCOPE_EXIT([f](){ baz(f); })

// how do I call commit on the above?
// I could use my editor to find the line number, but thats very fragile.
// And probably not what you intended to do.


bar(5); // It worked no exception
// So here I would expect to call commit.
```

If you can not call `commit()` then you should remove it from the class.

I would just get rid of the macors. Then your users can do:

```
auto guard = makeScopeGuard([](){revertStuff();}
// DO WORK HERE

// WORK DONE
guard.commit(); // no exceptions so we commit and don't need to revert.
```

### An example working with correct move semantics fo the pedants:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


class ScopeGuard
{
public:
    ScopeGuard(std::function<void()>&& func)
        : committed_(false)
        , valid_(true)
        , rollbackFunc_(std::move(func))
    {}

    ~ScopeGuard() noexcept
    {
        if (valid_ && !committed_)
            rollbackFunc_();
    }

    ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
    ScopeGuard& operator=(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;

    ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
        : committed_(false)
        , valid_(false)
    {
        swap(other);
    }

    ScopeGuard& operator=(ScopeGuard&& other) noexcept
    {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(ScopeGuard& other)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(committed_,    other.committed_);
        swap(valid_,        other.valid_);
        swap(rollbackFunc_, other.rollbackFunc_);
    }

    void commit() const { committed_ = true; }

private:
    mutable bool          committed_;
    bool                  valid_;
    std::function<void()> rollbackFunc_;␣
};

ScopeGuard makeScopeGuard(std::function<void()>&& func)
{
    return ScopeGuard(std::move(func));
}


#define MY_CONCATENATE_NX(A, B) A ## B
#define MY_CONCATENATE(A, B) MY_CONCATENATE_NX(A, B)

#define SCOPE_EXIT(f) auto MY_CONCATENATE(EXIT, __LINE__) = makeScopeGuard(f);

int foo(const char*) noexcept {std::cout << "food\n";return 0;}
bool bar(int) noexcept {std::cout << "bar\n";return true;}
void baz(int) noexcept {std::cout << "baz\n";}

int main() {
    int f = foo("/dev/random");
    if (!f)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    SCOPE_EXIT([f](){ baz(f); })
    int b = 1;
    bar(b);
    baz(f)    
}
```

Comment: I believe ut should be `std::exchange()` for move constructor, as it better matches semantics

Comment: Example in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) uses it to implement move constructor

Comment: @Incomputable Interesting. I have not seen that before. Not yet convinced that it provides better semantics (or that it is more standard). I see it works well for small POD like objects. But when you start getting complicated members it will start to be less efficient (As you have to construct that member to put in place (less efficient as you already have that member constructed at destination)). Then you have a dichotomy in that some moves are done with `swap()` and others with `exchange()`. Seems much smaller maintenance cost to make the move semantics implemented the same way everywhere.

Comment: I see what you mean. I agree on complications it brings. May be with time, as idioms will be more widespread, they will be better. If you're interested, here is 3.5 minute [talk](https://youtu.be/OqJUBIJOojI) at cppcon on `std::exchange()` idioms. I believe it is the same swap, it just returns the value.

Comment: Actually, `makeScopeGuard` isn't accepting a rvalue reference, but a so-called forwarding reference (since `Lambda` gets deduced). This means that `makeScopeGuard` accepts both rvalue and lvalue references, so `std::forward<Lambda>(func)` should be called instead of `std::move(func)` (Otherwise, if called with a lvalue reference to a functor, the functor will be moved from, which very likely is not intended. E.g. `auto f = std::function<void()>([&](){ doStuff();}); SCOPE_EXIT(f); /* f got moved from, so this call is not valid anymore: */ f();`).

Comment: @hoffmale: Seem to be half correct (based on a test I did). Yes I should be using forward. But luckily the above will not break as the `func` parameter will not bind when using std::move and thus it does not compile.

Comment: @phynju  Your `rollbackFunc_` is a reference. Don't make it a reference. There are functions already for that. Note: This is a code review I did not cover everything only the obvious stuff. If you want to know how to remove a reference you need to ask on SO.

Comment: When you use lambda to declare scopeguard variable, the class type will different each declaration. In that situation, there is no way to move, cause all scopeguard variables are different class types.

Comment: @phynju Are you looking for help into a specific problem or complaining about something in the review above?

Comment: I was saying the move assignment not working and I tried to elaborate the reason in previous comment.

Comment: @phynju Sure. The move assignment may not work if you take the original code and directly cut and paste in my code. But that was never the point. I am trying to show better ways to write the code. And you can easily change things so it will work.

Comment: @phynju Updated answer with working version that can be moved. You don't even need to make the Scope a template. Just stick in a `std::function`

Answer (score 2):

Making a copy of the lambda there is going to hurt you a little bit, at least in practice. Anyway, I strongly recommend using what I call "the `Auto` macro":

http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/~ajo/disseminate/auto.h

```
int main() {
    int f = foo("/dev/random");
    if (!f) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    Auto(baz(f));
    int b = 1;
    bar(b);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[VS2017 generates perfect code,](https://godbolt.org/g/ESkCC8) and as a (non-negligible) bonus, you end up with really nice syntax — no ugly `[](){ ... }` boilerplate. You just write the exact code you want to run — kind of like Go's `defer baz(f);` but even better (due to subtleties of eager evaluation in Go that aren't relevant here ;)).

Comment: This design is elegant. I want to fetch the object from Auto Macro, so that I can call its method later on. However I could not figure out how can I get the instance_, help please. @quuxplusone

Comment: @phynju: If you ask a detailed question on StackOverflow and "@" my username, I'll try to help out. My suspicion right now is that you're trying to do something that is *not* `Auto`'s use-case. If you just want a way to package up a behavior into an object you can "call later on," you're probably just looking for C++11 lambdas, or perhaps `std::function`, not a scoped syntactic construct like `Auto(...);`.

Comment: The main point of ScopeGuard is to branching exception and nonexception code. That is you will need to dismiss(or commit sometimes they call) when no-exception raised. I like the style Auto(fun(parameters)) you code support. however, any suggestions if to make it be able to be dismissed later on.

Comment: @phynju: You mean, like, `bool dismissed = false; Auto(if (!dismissed) do_something()); ... dismissed = true; ...`?

Comment: Not exactly. add a dismiss method to the class `void dismiss(){this.mDismiss=true;}` and destructor `~AtScopeExit() { if(!mDismiss)m_lambda(); }` , so then do this: `auto obj = Auto(reversefun(...)); FollowUpOperation(); obj.dismiss();` So that when FollowUpOperation(); raised exception, the  `reversefun()` will be called, otherwise, no. As I understand from [ScopeGuard by Andrei Alexandrescu and Petru Marginean](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758). So the problem is  how can I get the object (`obj` here) created by Auto be refereed later.

Comment: I prefer the control variable `dismissed` in the class, as they are strongly related.

Comment: @phynju: You can do that (see OP's original code in this question), but it is (IMHO) less simple and less visually clear than the `Auto` macro.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: MSVC does some extra stuff and really doesn't like the call to `makeScopeGuard`.

To elaborate:

The `main` functions in the original examples only takes 16 instruction (GCC) or 23 (+8 inside `makeScopeGuard`) instructions (MSVC) respectively.

GCC inlined everything it could, proved that `valid_` and `committed_` don't change (so they are basically constant), elided the branch and variable allocations, and just calls `baz(f)` directly before exiting.

MSVC, however, only inlines the destructor of `ScopeGuard` into `main` and the constructor of `ScopeGuard` into `makeScopeGuard`. MSVC seems unable to inline the call to `makeScopeGuard` or to prove that `valid_` and `committed_` don't actually change values (so it has to create them on the stack and generate instructions/calls for them).

But this can be improved! Changing the macro so it doesn't call `makeScopeGuard` suddenly allows MSVC to come to the same conclusions as GCC and remove the checks and thus the stack allocations.

```
#define SCOPE_EXIT(f) auto MY_CONCATENATE(EXIT_lambda, __LINE__) = f;\
    auto MY_CONCATENATE(EXIT_var, __LINE__) =\
    ScopeGuard<decltype(MY_CONCATENATE(EXIT_lambda, __LINE__))>{std::move(MY_CONCATENATE(EXIT_lambda, __LINE__))};
```

MSVC still does produce some extra instructions (for the `ScopeGuard`'s and the lambdas constructors and destructors), but those are never actually called.
The final count for `main` of MSVC would be 19 instructions (only 3 more than GCC because it does some stack pointer management, though that could probably be turned off with the right compiler switch).

[Link to godbolt with fixed macro (MSVC)](https://godbolt.org/g/C8PBb8)

Comment: Working around the compiler is not a good way to do things. If the compiler is not generating perfect code it has a reason. Now it could be that its optimizations are not perfect yet. But they will get better over time. So it is best to write more readable code and let the compiler get better over time. Thus your code is always readable and thus maintainable and eventually the compiler will generate perfect code but will always generate correct code.

Comment: @LokiAstari: My intention was not to "show how to beat the optimizer", but to "explain what the optimizer does". I'm with you that usually correct maintainable code is more important, but sometimes that extra edge in performance is needed. Also, it's interesting to try and understand why the compiler isn't able to do some optimizations (e.g. in order to find why your code might not be conforming). After all, the optimizer doesn't look at UB and correctness the way we do!